# store Os.system result in variable

Tags: python, linux, variables, os.system

hello guys i'm wondering how to store `os.system` result in variable

as we know it's return 0

so i'm wondering what i should do to store the result

and second question : how to get ip in Linux  [ somebody will suggest `ifconfig`] but `ifconfig` show so many result i just wana the `IP`

Comment: **One question per question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from subprocess import *

def run_cmd(cmd):
        p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
        output = p.communicate()[0]
        return output
```

As for the second question, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/read-unixlinux-system-ip-address-in-a-shell-script.html

Comment: I'm not sure I am crazy about the 'from subprocess import *' Bemmu.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're first question is a python question, here is how to get the IP address in linux using python:

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

ifname='eth0'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
address = socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
                    s.fileno(),
                    0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
                    struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
                    )[20:24])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can Create Subprocess.pipe and can print output of ifconfig
Here is a code for Ref:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
subprocess.call(["ifconfig","en0”])
p=subprocess.Popen(["ifconfig","en0"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    print line
```