# Handle result of os.system

Tags: python, os.system

I'm using python to script a functional script and I can't handler the result of this command line:

```
os.system("ps aux -u %s | grep %s | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'" % (username, process_name)
```

It shows me pids but I can't use it as List.

If I test:

```
pids = os.system("ps aux -u %s | grep %s | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'" % (username, process_name)
print type(pids)

#Results
29719
30205
31037
31612
<type 'int'>
```

Why is `pids` an `int`? How can I handle this result as `List`?

Stranger part:

```
print type(os.system("ps aux -u %s | grep %s | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'" % (username, process_name))
```

There is nothing. Not any type written on my console..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, os.system for command-line call (linux) not returning what it should?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791465/python-os-system-for-command-line-call-linux-not-returning-what-it-should)

Comment: @Holt This is close to a duplicate, but the linked question does not have `shell=True`, which will break considering the OP is using pipes here. Did you find any with `shell=True`?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco This one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276614/store-os-system-result-in-variable?rq=1) has a `shell=True` using `Popen`, even if it is not needed by the other OP. My though is that there are plenty of posts on SO (and elsewhere) asking for `How to get the result of a shell command?`, and adding new ones just makes everything confusing for someone looking for an answer (IMO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.system` does not capture the output of the command it runs. To do so you need to use `subprocess`.

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output("your command goes here", shell=true)
```

---

The above will work in Python 2.7.  For older Pythons, use:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("your command goes here", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Can you share information where it is written in official documentation?

Comment: That's good. Thank you! I've added this line to have a List `out.split('\n')`. By the way, there is a typing error on the first command (shell=True) with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

[os module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

> **os.system(command)**
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command.
>
> **On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent.**

If you want access to the output of the command, use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead, e.g. `check_output`:

> **subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)**
>
> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.